# How to use Bootstrap modal using the anchor tag for Register?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of anchor tags for my navigation bar. I want to open a modal when "Register" is clicked. Here is the code:

```
 <li><a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Home")">Login</a></li>
 <li><a href="#"> data-toggle="modal" data-target="modalRegister"> Register</a></li>

<div id="modalRegister" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align-last: center">Register</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I normally use a button to open a modal, but I'm not quite sure how I would open it using the `<a></a>` tag because of the `<a href""></a>`. How can I achieve the results?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You will have to modify the below line:

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="modalRegister">Register</a></li>
```

`modalRegister` is the ID and hence requires a preceding `#` for ID reference in html.

So, the modified html code snippet would be as follows:

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegister">Register</a></li>
```

Answer (score 13):

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Note: For `<a>` elements, omit data-target, and use `href="#modalID"` instead.

Comment: Please include the text from the link and explain it here. Once the link goes stale, your answer becomes useless.

Comment: Can you Please explain it clearly. I am unable to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to W3Schools that answers your question
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Note: For anchor tag elements, omit data-target, and use href="#modalID" instead:

I hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Just replace it:

```
<li><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegister">Register</a></li>
```

Instead of:

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="modalRegister">Register</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is your code**

```
<li><a href="#"> data-toggle="modal" data-target="modalRegister"> Register</a></li>
```

in your code, you have to change like below

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegister"> Register</a></li>
```